# How to loop an arima model to run over different columns of a time series data?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

So I have a data set which has district wise values of covid-19 cases. Now I want to run an Arima model on each of these districts and create a similar dataset of predicted values.

```
  library("forecast")
    df <- read.csv("D:/Hackathon/Time series/Maharashtra.csv")
    z = ncol(df)
    for(i in z){
      x = ts(c[,i],frequency = 365, start = c(2020,1,30))
      plot.ts(x)
      pi = auto.arima(x)
      summary(pi)
      q = forecast(pi,h=30)
      plot.forecast(q)
      write.csv(q,"D:/Hackathon/pred.csv")
}
```

I know for a fact this is not correct. This how the data is

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific - what is not correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)).

Comment: See the fable package which is designed to tackle this exact problem. An example is given at https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/fable/

Comment: Thank you all. I would use the fable package as suggested by Rob and post the results. Regards.